# Kazhdan-Lusztig basis of the symmetric group algebra $\mathbb{K}S_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, coxeter-groups, hecke-algebras, kazhdan-lusztig

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $\mathbb{K}$ a field. Denote by $\mathbb{K}S_n$ the symmetric group algebra.

What's Kazhdan-Lusztig basis of $\mathbb{K}S_n$? I think that the basis is a $\mathbb{K}$-linear combination of the elements in $S_n$. But I don't know the specific form.

Comment: How specific do want it to be? The definition of the Kazhdan-Lusztig basis is effective in the sense that it gives you a (not particular practical though) way to construct it algorithmically. You can do that in the Hecke algebra, then substitute 1 for the polynomial indeterminate and you get the KL-basis in the group algebra. (And you can be more efficient by using better algorithms to compute the KL-polynomials). In what sense is that not a "specific" description of the basis? What do you want to do that this level of specificity isn't enough?

Comment: Another way of looking at the KL-basis: It is a particular cellular basis in the sense of Graham-Lehrer.

Comment: I'm also not quite clear about what precisely is being asked.   It may (or may not) be helpful to point out a 1988 paper by Garsia and McLarnan: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870888900606

Comment: @  Johannes Hahn  I want to know what's KL-basis of symmetric group algebra $\mathbb{K}S_n$?

Comment: @  Jim Humphreys Thank you very much.

Comment: @bing That's not a helpful question.  The definition is easily found in a reference, and (at least to my knowledge) there's no significant simplification of it in the symmetric group case.

Comment: @  Ben Webster Thank you. I know that the Heck algebra $H_n(1) \cong \mathbb{C}S_n$. The KL-basis of $\mathbb{C}S_n$ is dermined by KL-polynomial.

Comment: You understand that the Hecke algebra can be defined over $\mathbb{K}$, right?

Comment: @ David Hill  I know very little about Hecke algebra. Could you add some knowledge about Hecke algebra? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is too big a question to be answered in a meaningful way here.  (We could give you one of several definitions, but none of them would mean anything to you.)  If you'd like an algebraic approach, read most of Humphrey's book.  If you'd like a combinatorial approach, read most of the book by Bjorner and Brenti.

Comment: @ Alexander Woo Ok, thank you for your suggestions.